# What library will allow to manage polygon on the map view?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Is there any library (cocoapod would be best) to create polygon on the map view?

Not from the code, from the user view.

As a user I can:

- start creating polygon
- move points
- delete points
- add another points

That is all I need.

Comment: Are native methods not good enough for you? What would this library do as from functionality perspective that would benefit you opposing using `UIBezierPath` and arrays of `CGPoint`s? Map view has all the methods it needs to convert on screen coordinates to map coordinates and vice versa...

Comment: I need to develop in code: creating, dragging, deleting points. Updating polygon. A whole staff may be done already by someone. I simply could long press add new point, ad another points. Drag to move. Tap to delete.

Comment: So you mean like instead of writing `points.append(MKMapView().convert(gesure.location(in: mapView), toCoordinateFrom: mapView))` you would write `someLibraryObject.addPoint(gesure.location(in: mapView), toCoordinateFrom: mapView))`?

Comment: hmm, you may be right here, but I mean a whole stuff: delete pointers, move pointers. Draw polygon smoothly, update polygon...

Answer (score 1):

As per comments even finding such a tool will be no shortcut from what you are having with native components. Your issue is probably more interesting from UX perspective then any other. You would need to provide what your requirements are from that perspective but let us assume a few:

1. User may use map normally as if no annotations were added.
2. User may add polygons to his map.
3. There may be any number of polygons.
4. Each polygon may have any number of points.

Now let us position ourself into user perspective where user has 4 polygons each with N points and he would like to add another point in second polygon he has created previously. How does he do that? We need to identify that adding a point will effect that specific polygon and not the last one or a new one...

Let us imagine another situation where user has created 2 polygons which intersect and one polygon is drawn over the other. May user change the order of those so the other one is at the bottom? If the answer to this is "yes" then we must definitely start with a list of polygons. It might be that we get to the same situation with points so each polygon then has a list of points...

At some point you might be able to remove all the lists (visually) and replace them with gesture recognizers or whatever but that makes no difference from the code perspective when building this thing of yours. I would suggest your data structure to be like:

```
class Polygon {
    class Point {
        var location: CLLocationCoordinate
        init(location: CLLocationCoordinate) { self.location = location }
    }

    var points: [Point] = []
}
```

Then your system simply contains an array of those:

```
private var polygons: [Polygon] = []
```

Then you will need some gesture recognizers and states so you have a method like:

```
private func handleGestureRecognizerEvent(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, forState state: State) {
    switch state {
    case .idle:
        if let closest = findPolygonCloseTo(recognizer.location(in: mapView)) {
            self.state = .selectedPolygon(polygon: closest)
        } else {
            // Nothing to do here
        }
    case .selectedPolygon(let polygon):
        if let closest = findPointCloseTo(recognizer.location(in: mapView), belongingTo: polygon) {
            self.state = .selectedPoint(point: closest, inPolygon: polygon) // Selected a point within current polygon
        } else if let closest = findPolygonCloseTo(recognizer.location(in: mapView)) {
            self.state = .selectedPolygon(polygon: closest) // Selected another polygon
        } else {
            self.state = .idle // Selected nothing so go back to idle
        }
    case .selectedPoint(let point, let polygon):
        switch gesture.state {
        case .begin: // TODO: same as selected polygon but revert to selected polygon instead of idle
        case .moved: point.location = self.coordinateForPoint(recognizer.location(in: mapView))
        // TODO: add other scenarios if needed
        }
    }
}
```

From this perspective all you need is to find coordinate from point which is `points.append(MKMapView().convert(gesure.location(in: mapView), toCoordinateFrom: mapView))`. And you need to find if point is within polygon which already [exists natively](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624345-containspoint).

So then on add point you only need to add it within the selected polygon (or create a new polygon if none is selected). On delete you need to have a point selected...

I hope this puts you on the right track...

Comment: Yes, thank you for your reply. SImply user can create only one polygon on the map in my app for now..

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk that makes things a little bit simpler as you drop one case in states. You did use plural in your title so I assumed you had multiple...

Comment: apologize for that. But I understand it now;) Thank you for your help. I will use it.